# Why is strlen calculating the length is two higher than the length actually is?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION["word"])) {
    $dictionary_file = new SplFileObject("dictionary.txt");
    $dictionary_file->seek(rand(0, 80367));
    $_SESSION["word"] = $dictionary_file->current();
    $_SESSION["word_progress"] = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($_SESSION["word"]); $i++) {
        $_SESSION["word_progress"] .= "_";
    }
    echo strlen($_SESSION["word"]);
    echo $_SESSION["word"];
}
else {
    if (isset($_GET["guess"])) {
        // If their guessed letter is in the word
        if (stripos($_SESSION["word"], $_GET["guess"]) !== false) {
            $occurrence_points = strposall($_SESSION["word"], $_GET["guess"]);
            $progress = $_SESSION["word_progress"];

            foreach ($occurrence_points as $values) {
                $progress[$values] = $_GET["guess"];
            }

            $_SESSION["word_progress"] = $progress;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I randomly generate a word from a file. Say it generates "bubble". The length is 6, but it will report 8, even after printing it out and confirming the word is indeed bubble. Why is this?

Comment: Do you need to `trim()` it before you check its length?

Comment: I suspect a CRLF being appended to the string which form the "line".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the randomly generated word might be adding whitespace. do a trim()

```
   $_SESSION["word"] = trim($dictionary_file->current());
```